# Switch Git branch in development server

Tags: git, version-control, merge, smartgit

I have a Git repository structured as pic shows:

[image]

As you may see there is a `development` branch, that's the one I'm using at development server.

We are working (I and them) in new functionalities so developers works at `unificacion` branch and I continue developing at `development`, in order to not messing up things at "stable" development I have created `merge-all` which contains a merge between `development` and `unificacion`. Well, I need to swtich from `development` to `merge-all` in development server, how I do that?

I have this content at `.git/config` file but I'm not so sure to touch anything there.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@bitbucket.org:iosev/sis-php-source.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Can any give me some tips? I have read some docs ([this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), [this](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/) and so on) but still not clear at all to me

Comment: `git checkout merge-all`

Also I would recommend reading about the Gitflow branching model to simplify your workflow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Switching between branches use
    git checkout merge-all

Read below all you need to know about branching and merging
    http://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
```